# Reading rows from mysql large table

Tags: java, mysql

I need to select specific rows from  large mysql table and do some  string operations with columns and write results to file, Which will be the fastest method for these? I have some code using hibernate but it runs very slow.

Comment: well generally you SELECT data FROM table... not sure what you want with this question. but if you want to do some string operations you need to be more specific on what you want to do.. theres a lot of things you can do to a string.

Comment: Write a query.  Optimize the indexes.  That would be the normal course of action.

Comment: Show us the code. This table is large, like, how large? Can you call a select from the application without permGen?